Multiple regression confidence intervals for slope coefficient of a covariate
When constructing such a confidence interval and evaluating whether it contains 0 (for the t test to see if the covariate is of relevance in the regression) are the other variables being controlled or held constant at some levels (their mean?)
Wackerley, Mendenhall and Schaffer have the following question.
Consider the general linear model
$$Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1 + ... + \beta_k x_k + \epsilon$$
where $E(\epsilon) = 0$ and $V(\epsilon) = 0$. They then ask to verify that $E(\hat{\beta}_i) = \beta_i$ and $V(\hat{\beta}_i) = c_{ii}\sigma^2$, where $c_{ii}$ is the element in row $i$ and column $i$ of $(X'X)^{-1}$
So, in constructing say the $100(1-\alpha)\%$ confidence interval for $\beta_i$, they have: $\hat{\beta}_i \pm t^{n-k-1}_{\frac{\alpha}{2}} S \sqrt{c_{ii}} $. What is the precise interpretation of this interval especially as it relates to what is happening to other variables -- are they fixed or controlled for in some sense?
My question arises because in stating the hypothesis test (t test to see if the covariate is significant), they only state:
$$H_0: \beta_i = 0$$
$$H_a: \beta_i \neq 0$$
without explicitly stating whether this test controls for other variables or fixes them at some level or not. What exactly is happening to the other variables when performing this test?

An advantage of multiple regression is that all predictors are considered together in the model. Each coefficient represents the change in outcome associated with a change in the corresponding predictor when all other predictors are held constant.
If there aren't interaction terms combining predictors and you have a simple linear model as in your example, then it doesn't matter which levels of the other predictors are chosen.
If there are interaction terms involving two or more predictors you have to be careful, as coefficient estimates can depend on details of how the predictors are coded. See this answer for a simple worked-through example. In the default treatment coding of categorical predictors used by R, the coefficient for a predictor involved in an interaction term will be the estimate when all of the interacting predictors are at values of 0 or at their categorical reference levels.
The previous paragraph illustrates the danger in your approach:

constructing such a confidence interval and evaluating whether it contains 0 (for the t test to see if the covariate is of relevance in the regression)

specifically for a predictor involved in an interaction term. It's even worse than that, however. There is no substantive reason to omit any outcome-associated predictor from a model just because it doesn't pass some magical test threshold like $p < 0.05$. There's a substantial risk of omitted-variable bias when you proceed that way, and you have all of the difficulties that come with automated model selection.

Is the following interpretation of the CI correct? In repeated sampling, with the same values of the x variables, and keeping all other estimates b_0, b_2,...,b_k the same as we obtain by least squares using the current sample, if we estimate b_1 again and again using least squares such that the residuals are minimized against the new ys obtained in repeated sampling, with 95% confidence, the true population beta_1 will be covered by the b_1 +/- tmultiple se_b1 ?

@One_Cable5781 yes, if I understand what you wrote correctly. This site's tag info for confidence interval goes into a bit more detail.
